Can I show that a certain ideal over a valuation ring is finitely generated?
I am interested in the following situation:
Let $X$ be an affine variety defined over an algebraically closed field $k$ with a non-trivial non-archimedian valuation, for example the complex Puiseux series. Let $I \subseteq k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ be the defining ideal of $X$.
We now form the closure $\overline{X} = V(I \cap k^\circ[x_1, \dots, x_n])$ in affine space $\mathbb{A}_{k^\circ}^n = \operatorname{spec}(k^\circ[x_1, \dots, x_n])$ defined over the valuation ring $k^\circ$. I want to understand whether $\overline{X}$ is of finite presentation, i.e. whether the ideal $J = I \cap k^\circ[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ is finitely generated. Since $k^\circ$ is not Noetherian, this is a-priory not clear.
What I have tried so far: We show that we can find elements in $J$ that generate the ideal, both when restricted to the generic fiber and over the special fiber. More precisely, denote by $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq k^\circ[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ the (prime) ideal generated by the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} \subseteq k^\circ$. Now $k^\circ[x_1, \dots, x_n]/\mathfrak{p} = \widetilde{k}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ is a Noetherian ring by the Hilberts Basis Theorem. We can pick elements $f_1, \dots, f_s$ of $J$ whose residues generate $J\otimes_{k^\circ}\widetilde{k}$. In the situation that I am interested in I also know that the ideal $I$ is generated by elements in $k^\circ[x_1, \dots, x_n]$, so by enlarging the list $f_1, \dots, f_s$ we may also assume that these elements generate $I = k\otimes_{k^\circ}J$.
In summary we know that $\langle f_1, \dots, f_s \rangle \otimes_{k^\circ} k = J\otimes_{k^\circ} k$ , and $\langle f_1, \dots, f_s \rangle \otimes_{k^\circ} \widetilde{k} =  J 
 \otimes_{k^\circ} \widetilde{k}$. Over a Noetherian base I would be able to believe that this is enough to show that $\langle f_1, \dots, f_s \rangle = J.$
By passing to the quotient of $\langle f_1, \dots, f_s \rangle$ we are left with showing that an ideal $J$ of the coordinate ring $A = k^\circ[x_1, \dots, x_n]/\langle f_1, \dots, f_s \rangle$ vanishes. $J$ is a module over the valuation ring $k^\circ$ with the property that all geometric points vanish. Since the module is not of finite type, and the base is not Noetherian I do not know how to proceed.
The following question also seems not to address this.

Because you took the Zariski closure it’s flat, and flat + finite presentation over a (rank $1$) complete valuation ring is finite presentation. In fact, here’s an even crazier fact proved by Raynaud—Gruson: if $A$ is a finite type $R$-algebra where $R$ is a domain, then $A$ is of finite presentation.

(I forgot to say flat!!)

Here’s a remarkable theorem of Raynaud—Gruson.

Theorem ([RG, Première partie, Corollaire (3.4.7)]): Let $R$ be an integral domain, and let $A$ be a flat, finite type $R$-algebra. Then,
$A$ is finitely presented.

Suppose now that $R=V$ is a valuation ring. Then, it’s well-known that a $V$-module $M$ is flat if and only if it’s torsion-free (i.e., for every $v\in V$ the map $v\cdot (-)\colon M\to M$ is injective) — for example, see Tag 0539. Thus, we arrive at the following nice corollary.

Corollary: Let $V$ be a valuation ring. Then, a torsion-free $V$-algebra $A$ is finitely generated if and only if it’s finitely
presented.

So, let $K=\mathrm{Frac}(V)$, and let $I\subseteq K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ be an ideal. Set $I_V=I\cap V[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$. Then, $A=V[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/I_V$ is a finite type $V$-algebra. But, it’s also torsion-free. Indeed, observe that $A$ embeds into $K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/I$ which is torsion-free. Thus, by the above corollary, $A$ is of finite presentation.
[RG] Raynaud, M. and Gruson, L., 1971. Critères de platitude et de projectivité: Techniques de≪ platification≫ d'un module. Inventiones mathematicae, 13, pp.1-89.

I find the statement "flat and of finite type over a domain implies finitely presented" very surprising.
